# Upper Troposphere temperature with 1K increase of surface temperature

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [Estimate the change in temperature in upper troposphere when there is a 1K surface temperature increase](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/429208/estimate-the-change-in-temperature-in-upper-troposphere-when-there-is-a-1k-surfa)

I was directed here to ask a homework question.  Linked to original question. Please, any help!

Comment: Assuming you are taking about the only comment on that post, you were not directed here to ask the question. Instead, you were directed to two specific posts that discuss details of why your question is considered off-topic.

Comment: Re *"I was directed here to ask a homework question."*: No, it said *"Please see this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions and this Meta post for "check my work" problems."*

Comment: [Here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/32426) can you see some tips, how can you ask here questions considered homework-like by the majority of the voters. You might also try some of our sister sites, for example https://earthscience.stackexchange.com , it has more lenient rules (although your question might be a duplicate there). A complete list of all science/technology SE sites are [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science-questions).

Comment: ? This question is clearly about the PSE...

Comment: @peterh oh, that was me. I don't really think that this is about Physics SE. It's asking for an estimate for the change in the temperature in the upper troposphere for a given change in the surface temperature. It's just like the other cases where people have asked physics questions on the meta site.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, whoever directed you here gave you some misguided advice, since the purpose of this site is not really to provide people with homework help. We prefer to focus on the kinds of questions that a student or researcher might ask simply because they're interested; for example, clarifying a confusing paragraph in a research paper or explaining an apparent inconsistency in a textbook's explanation of some concept. (That's not an exhaustive list, just a couple of examples of the kinds of questions we prefer to handle.)

If what you really want is to get help with a homework problem you're working on, it's probably best for you to try somewhere else that's more focused on giving that kind of help. You can sometimes get that help in our [main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71) or [a dedicated problem solving strategies room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/problem-solving-strategies), if you have access to chat. (That requires a certain amount of reputation on the Stack Exchange network.) Otherwise, you might try something from [our list of other sites that deal with physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site) and may be able to handle questions that are off topic here.

In some cases it is possible to ask a question that will get you the help you need with your homework in a way that still fits on this site. There's some information about how to do that in our [policy on homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange), but it can be tricky to get the question in the right form without some help. If you want to try that, that's definitely something you could ask about in the chat room (again, if you have access) or on this meta site. The main restriction is that you should quote the homework problem you're working on, but don't ask for the answer to that problem itself. Instead, narrow it down to some specific conceptual issue that you can't figure out, e.g. something that might be useful to other people doing other problems, and ask about that. You would need to summarize the work you did to narrow down the original homework problem to the specific question you're asking, and also show that you made [some effort to figure out that specific question yourself](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question) before you came to us.